# TypeError: list.fields[order.name] is undefined

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

We are currently trying to upgrade to odoo 11 (from 10). We could fix most issues of our custom modules while installing them in new odoo 11 but now i get the following runtime error:

```
TypeError: list.fields[order.name] is undefined
http://10.15.0.183:8069/web/content/975-35dc0a2/web.assets_backend.js:1293
Traceback:
compareRecords@http://10.15.0.183:8069/web/content/975-35dc0a2/web.assets_backend.js:1293:190
```

Any ideas whats wrong? Any possibility to debug this or to find out where this exactly happens? the Traceback does not tell anything and in odoo-server log there is nothing.

we have different custom moduls extending articles,customers..

Answer (score 1):

Try to unpack js files to get a better js error that will lead you exactly to where is located the issue, or at least a clear path to start debugging the JS issue in the browser. Try to reproduce the issue starting the page load from this URL

http://10.15.0.183:8069/web?debug=assets

you can also activate debugging mode from the Settings app or using a plugin for your browser:

- [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odoo-debug/hmdmhilocobgohohpdpolmibjklfgkbi)
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/odoo-easy-debug/)

Comment: indeed, with assets enabled you can see the original js files and use the debugger of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I had the same problem today.

I'm just sharing the fix in my case (Axel Mendoza "debug=assets" answer helped me to pinpoint the bug).

The problem was a mistake in a form view :
a `<tree>` element was used to render a many2many field, and the `default_order` attribute was referencing a field not used inside the `<tree>` definition.
Wrong XML :

```
<field name="my_many2many_field">
<tree default_order="my_field_0">
<field name="my_field_1"/>
<field name="my_field_2"/>
</tree>
</field>
```

In my case the fix was to add the field referenced by the `default_order` attribute, as an invisible field, inside the `<tree>` definition.
Fixed XML :

```
<field name="my_many2many_field">
<tree default_order="my_field_0">
<field name="my_field_0" invisible="1"/>
<field name="my_field_1"/>
<field name="my_field_2"/>
</tree>
</field>
```